# how to return value to next function - not in class

Tags: python, function, methods

i have a code with 2 function
i would like to return the value of 1 function to the other

for now its return "none"

i have 2 function :
1 for vaildip address and the other function should get the values and use them when appaend to file:

right now the validip works in a loop and ask for vaild ip but when the function finish all the 4 inputs its return "none" as value

```
def vaildIP(message):
    while True:
      answer1 = raw_input(message)
      ip = answer1.split('.')
      if (len(ip) == 4) and (1 <= int(ip[0]) <= 223) and (int(ip[0]) != 127) and (int(ip[0]) != 169 or int(ip[1]) != 254) and (
           0 <= int(ip[1]) <= 255 and 0 <= int(ip[2]) <= 255 and 0 <= int(ip[3]) <= 255):
          break
          return answer
      else:
          print "Please Enter A Vaild IP Address"
          continue





def setNetwork():
    print "[Network Interface] This step is for configuring the primary network interface (eth0) with a static IP address."
    print "[Network Interface] Please provide the new configuration values, or press Enter to use the current value."
    print "[Network Interface] Prior to saving the new values you will have the option to review them."

    address = vaildIP('Address[current value is < no - value >]:')
    netmask = vaildIP('Netmask[current value is < no - value >]:')
    gateway = vaildIP('Gateway[current value is < no - value >]:')
    print "[Network Interface] Please provide the DNS servers to use (one or more, separated with spaces), \n  or press Enter to use the existing value."
    dns = vaildIP('DNS servers [current value is <no-value>]:') or "8.8.8.8"

    print ("[Network Interface] These will be the new settings for eth0:\n" "iface eth0 inet static\n""Address {addressip} \n"
           "Netmask {netmaskip}\n" "Gateway {gatewayip}\n" "dns-nameservers {dnsip}".format(addressip=address, netmaskip=netmask, gatewayip=gateway, dnsip=dns))
    print ("Enter 'y' - to save the new configuration and load it.\n" "Enter 'n' - to re-enter the configuration details.\n" "Enter 'q' - to quit and return to main manu.")
    option = raw_input()
    if option == 'y':
        newlines = ('auto lo \n iface lo inet loopback \n # The primary network interface \n auto eth0 \n iface eth0 inet static \n address %s \n netmask %s \n gateway %s \n dns-nameservers %s ' % (
        address, netmask, gateway, dns))
        with open("/Users/yos/Desktop/net1.txt", "w+") as file:
            file.write(newlines)
    elif option == 'n':
        setNetwork()
    elif option == 'q':
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    setNetwork()
```

expected:

[Network Interface] These will be the new settings for eth0:
iface eth0 inet static
Address 1.1.1.1 #vaildip
Netmask 2.2.2.2 
Gateway 3.3.3.3
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
Enter 'y' - to save the new configuration and load it.
Enter 'n' - to re-enter the configuration details.
Enter 'q' - to quit and return to main manu.
n

actual results:
[Network Interface] These will be the new settings for eth0:
iface eth0 inet static
Address None 
Netmask None
Gateway None
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
Enter 'y' - to save the new configuration and load it.
Enter 'n' - to re-enter the configuration details.
Enter 'q' - to quit and return to main manu.
n

Comment: Instead of doing so many `and int(ip[X]) != Y` you should check once for each segment if the IP if it is `in` an iterable (a tuple for example).

Comment: Remove the `break` from your loop and change your return from `return answer` to `return answer1`